# Showing unexpected token while executing Hibernate Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, struts2

When i excuting below query showing **org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: AGAINST near line 1, column 106 [SELECT NAME,address,country,district,state,cpr_no,age FROM tbl_patient_general WHERE MATCH (NAME,cpr_no) AGAINST (:params)]**

```
            Query q3 = session.createQuery("SELECT NAME,address,country,district,state,cpr_no,age FROM tbl_patient_general WHERE MATCH (NAME,cpr_no) AGAINST (:params)");
            q3.setParameter("params", name);
```

Comment: Just try by removing WHERE clause.

Comment: Still it's not working..

Comment: I guess the table name is wrong!! what is the beans/hibernate-pojo's name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using native SQL or HQL? In first case use `session.createSQLQuery()`.
AGAINST is not an HQL function/reserved word